# In how many ways can we arrange the books on the shelf then?

Tags: combinatorics

A bookshelf contains 10 novels, 8 programming, and 24 computer games books.

We would like to rearrange the books so that each subcategory is placed on one level of the shelf. In addition, we want to rearrange the books alphabetically based on the author's family name. If you have two books with the same author's family name, you may disregard their orders. In how many ways can we arrange the books on the shelf then?

I've struggled with this question in 2 days now, and every time i get the same answer, can you guys please help, and quickly please.

My first answer was $3!\cdot 10!\cdot 8!\cdot 24!$, which turned out to be wrong.

My second answer was $3!\cdot 226800\cdot 20160\cdot 9.69\cdot 10^{21}$, which turned out to be wrong.

My third answer was $3!\cdot 42!$ which turned out to be wrong.

And by the way, books names arent given in the question, which is probably not needed.

Comment: Well, what answer do you get and how did you get it?  Note:  since we aren't told how many name-coincidences there are, I don't see how you could get a precise number out of this.

Comment: my answer was 3! * 42! but that was wrong

Comment: Please edit your post to include that answer and to explain how you got it.  As I say, I don't see how to calculate much of anything without knowing how the names sort out.

Comment: another answer of mine was 3!*10!*8!*24!, but that was wrong aswell

Comment: another attempt of mine was 3!*226800*20160*9.69*10^21, and also that was wrong

Comment: It looks like you are just guessing.  If all the names are distinct then there is a unique way to order each category of book so that the authors are in alphabetical order.  Thus, in that case, the answer would be $3!=6$  But it gets more complicated if some of the names match.

Comment: Note:  I am assuming that each shelf can only contain a single subcategory, though you do not say that anywhere.  Nor do you say how many shelves there are...if there are more than $3$ then you have more choices.  Really, the problem is too vaguely worded to say much about.

Comment: Moreover you do not say how many books each shelf can accommodate.

Comment: since there is 3 categories it means there is 3 shelf

Comment: each categorie must be in one shelf

Comment: for example, novels could be in shelf 1,2 or 3.

Comment: or programming could be in shelf 1,2 or 3 you understand?

Comment: Again, nothing in the problem statement says that there are only $3$ shelves, though you could add that assumption if you liked.  Also, nothing in the problem statement prevents you from putting *all* the books onto a single shelf.  Again, you could add that assumption if you wanted.  But even if you add in those two assumptions, you are still left with not knowing how many of the names coincide.

Comment: but I'm telling you this is the given information in the question, there are 3 shelves, i'm not assuming something.

Comment: Have you quoted the question verbatim ?

Comment: try $3!$ assuming that no family names match.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand it, the answer is either $6$ or $27$.

If we assume that each subject is placed on a unique shelf, then the answer is $3!=6$. There are $3!$ ways to uniquely assign the subjects to each shelf. Since we are requiring the books to be placed in alphabetical order on each shelf, there is then one way to sort each subject on its assigned shelf. This is true even when there are repeated author names, since whenever there are repeated names we "disregard their orders". That is, if there are two books by King, call them King1 and King2, then we are considering ..., King1, King2, ... and ... King2, King1, ... to be the same arrangement, so there is really only one way to arrange the novels.

However, when the problem says "place each subcategory on one level of the shelf", that could mean that it is allowed to place multiple categories on a single shelf, so some shelves have multiple categories while other shelves empty. If that is the case, then the number of ways is $3\times 3\times 3$, because there are $3$ choices for the shelf of each subject. Again, once the shelves are assigned, there is then a unique way to place the books on the shelves in alphabetical order.

Answer (score -2):

First, we need to calculate the number of ways to arrange each subcategory separately.

For the 10 novels, we can arrange them alphabetically by the author's family name in 10! ways.

Similarly, for the 8 programming books, we can arrange them alphabetically by the author's family name in 8! ways.

And for the 24 computer games books, we can arrange them alphabetically by the author's family name in 24! ways.

To arrange the entire bookshelf, we need to choose the order of the subcategories first. There are 3 subcategories, so there are 3! = 6 ways to choose the order.

Once we have chosen the order of the subcategories, we can arrange the books within each subcategory according to the number of ways we calculated above.

Therefore, the total number of ways to arrange the books on the shelf is:

**6 x 10! x 8! x 24! ≈ 1.531 x 10^45**

So, there are *approximately* **1.531 x 10^45** ways to arrange the books on the shelf.

Comment: I'm sorry but that is the wrong answer. I've already tried that.

Comment: I think the answer you are referring to is wrong!

Comment: The books are placed in alphabetical order, so why permute ?